# What special html characters do I need to handle with FreeMarker

Tags: java, html, freemarker

For example FreeMarker doesn't work with `&nbsp;` and will throw an exception, which is fine, however you also cannot use the greater than or less than symbols (`<`, `>`) otherwise it will fail because it's not a properly formatted tag, and instead need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` which again makes sense.

With that in mind is there a list of the characters/encodings that need to converted in html to something FreeMarker needs and those that should not be converted? Or at the very least a list within FreeMarker's special characters that need to be converted. I can't assume it's all of them because `&nbsp;` doesn't work. Whenever I Google the question I keep getting pushed to the [Expressions user manual page on FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html) but I can't seem to find any details...

Comment: _"FreeMarker doesn't work with &nbsp; "_ -- what makes you believe this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, `&...;` means nothing to FreeMarker, thus, you can only use them inside string literals and outside FTL tags/interpolation, where FreeMarker will not try interpret anything. There's a special case where you can write comparison operators with `&gt;` and `&lt;`, yes, but the Manual only shows that inside a note box as a deprecated syntax (or if not, where else, because that needs to be fixed).

Comment: I should've been more explicit, this is within text and not within a tag. I created a template with raw > and < and it resulted in an exception, I had to use the &lt; and &gt;. I appreciate what you're saying but is there any other cases other than these two? I know it shouldn't interpret "&" but it is required for greater and less than. I did see the escape character \ for certain characters but it worked with a double quote without the need for an escape character...

Comment: What do you mean by "within text"? How does that template look and what exception do you get? (FreeMarker doesn't care about `<` and `>` in static text (unless the `<` is directly followed by `#` or `@` or `/#` or `/@`), so I assume that's not what you mean.)